# Attempting to install .NET framework 4 *full* installs *client* instead

Tags: installation, .net-framework, .net-4.0

On a Win7 SP1 32-bit machine, I initially had .NET 4 client installed and wanted to upgrade to .NET 4 full.

I downloaded the full installer dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe from Microsoft. After download the file showed 48.11MB, the correct size for the full package (vs. 41MB for the client).

I ran the installer and it first prompted to repair or remove the existing package. I chose to remove, so uninstalled the two parts, 4 extended and 4 client.

Reboot.

I reran the installer and it began installation, showing that it was installing the client. Though this raised an eyebrow for me, I let it run to completion, thinking it might be reporting the full install in sections. But after completion, I again ended up with 4 extended and 4 client installed!

Obviously I am missing something; ideas...?

Comment: What do you see exactly? Both of those profiles are included in the .NET Framework 4.0.  What makes you think you don't have the full profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET Framework Client Profile is a subset of the full .NET Framework.  When you install the full framework you get the Client Profile plus some additional assemblies which complete the framework.  So when say you have the Client Profile + Extended installed, you have the full framework installed.

Quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> [The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is] part of the .NET Framework. The .NET Framework is made up of the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile and .NET Framework 4 Extended components
>   that exist separately in Programs and Features.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that when Programs and Features reported Client and Extended components that meant that I had the client profile installed. Are you saying that if the client profile was installed (i.e. not the full profile) it would *not* report the Extended component? In other words, how can I tell whether I have the client or the full installed?

Comment: You are correct, you could uninstall the Extended component to get the "Client Profile" only.  You can tell you have to full because you have the Extended component.

Comment: Thanks for clarity on this, which was not at all obvious to me.